# Oracle: Identifying peak values in a time series

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following values in a column of table. there are two columns in table. The other column is having distinct dates in descending order.

```
3
4
3
21
4
4
-1
3
21
-1
4
4
8
3
3
-1
21
-1
4
```

The graph will be
[image]

I need only peaks higlighted in graph with circles in output

```
4
21
21
8
21
4
```

Comment: No id column or similar?

Comment: How do you define the order of the rows in the table?

Comment: If there is really only one column, the question doesn't make sense.  Data in a heap organized table is inherently unordered.  Your query implicitly requires results to be ordered so that you can look at the value from the "prior" and the "next" row.  But with nothing to order by, the concept of "prior" and "next" don't exist.  We can write a query that may happen to work today with small data sets but it will stop working correctly in the future when the data changes.

Comment: there are 2 columns. one is date and the number of positive feedback on that date. there are 19 different dates with it.

Comment: Please update the question with that information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b92dc/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST ( datetime, value ) AS
          SELECT DATE '2015-01-01', 3 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2015-01-02', 4 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2015-01-03', 3 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2015-01-04', 21 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2015-01-05', 4 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2015-01-06', 4 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2015-01-07', -1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2015-01-08', 3 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2015-01-09', 21 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2015-01-10', -1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2015-01-11', 4 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2015-01-12', 4 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2015-01-13', 8 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2015-01-14', 3 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2015-01-15', 3 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2015-01-16', -1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2015-01-17', 21 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2015-01-18', -1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2015-01-19', 4 FROM DUAL
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT datetime, value
FROM   (
  SELECT datetime,
         LAG( value ) OVER ( ORDER BY datetime ) AS prv,
         value,
         LEAD( value ) OVER ( ORDER BY datetime ) AS nxt
  FROM   test
)
WHERE   ( prv IS NULL OR prv < value )
AND     ( nxt IS NULL OR nxt < value )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b92dc/1/0)**:

```
|                  DATETIME | VALUE |
|---------------------------|-------|
| January, 02 2015 00:00:00 |     4 |
| January, 04 2015 00:00:00 |    21 |
| January, 09 2015 00:00:00 |    21 |
| January, 13 2015 00:00:00 |     8 |
| January, 17 2015 00:00:00 |    21 |
| January, 19 2015 00:00:00 |     4 |
```

Comment: @ShravanYadav - `order by null` might work today.  It might work tomorrow.  But assuming you plan on adding, removing, or modifying data, it will stop working some day.  It might be tomorrow.  It might be a week from now.  It might be just after you go live.  Murphy's Law being what it is, it'll probably be the least convenient time possible.

Comment: can we use rownum instead of datetime and null in order by clause??

Comment: `ROWNUM` (generated in another sub-query) has the same issues as `ORDER BY NULL` - you can use either but it is not guaranteed that the rows will be brought back in the correct order (if you are not ordering the rows by something). If you have a column you can use to guarantee the order then use it otherwise you are asking for esoteric errors to pop up in your application where it may suddenly stop (or start) working for no reason.

Answer (score 2):

So the peak is defined as the previous value and next value being less than the current value, and you can retrieve the previous an next using LAG() and LEAD() functions.

You really need some other column (e.g. my_date) to define the order of the rows, then you can:

```
select my_date,
       value
from   (select value,
               lag(value ) over (order by my_date) lag_value,
               lead(value) over (order by my_date) lead_value
        from   my_table)
where   value > coalesce(lag_value , value - 1) and
        value > coalesce(lead_value, value - 1);
```

This would not allow for a "double-peak" such as:

```
1,
15,
15,
4
```

... for which much more complex logic would be needed.

Comment: why need a id column when we have null or rownum??

Comment: Because the order of rows in a relational database is inherently undefined. When you insert rows into Oracle there is no guarantee that they will be returned in that order when you query them. You might try deleting some rows, and inserting a few more, to see what happens.

Comment: Oh, also rownum is an pseudocolumn -- it's only an attribute of the rows returned in a query, not of the rows in the database themselves.

Comment: what about null used by MT0??

Comment: It's the same as saying "I don't care what order the rows are in".

Comment: If you have a date column to order the rows by, then use that in place of id.

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness the row pattern matching example:

```
WITH source_data(datetime, value) AS (
    SELECT DATE '2015-01-01', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE '2015-01-02', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE '2015-01-03', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE '2015-01-04', 21 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE '2015-01-05', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE '2015-01-06', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE '2015-01-07', -1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE '2015-01-08', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE '2015-01-09', 21 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE '2015-01-10', -1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE '2015-01-11', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE '2015-01-12', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE '2015-01-13', 8 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE '2015-01-14', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE '2015-01-15', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE '2015-01-16', -1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE '2015-01-17', 21 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE '2015-01-18', -1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE '2015-01-19', 4 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT *
FROM
    source_data MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
        ORDER BY datetime
        MEASURES
            LAST(UP.datetime) AS datetime,
            LAST(UP.value) AS value
    ONE ROW PER MATCH
    PATTERN ((UP DOWN) | UP$)
    DEFINE
        DOWN AS DOWN.value < PREV(DOWN.value),
        UP AS UP.value > PREV(UP.value) 
    )
ORDER BY
    datetime
```

Comment: This will miss the peak at the very first row, if the value in the first row is greater than in the second row. To fix it, the definition of `UP` can be extended to include `or PREV(value) is null`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a much more sophisticated method available in Oracle 12c, which is to use pattern matching SQL.

http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/pattern.htm#DWHSG8966

It would be overkill for a situation like this, but if you needed more complex patterns matched, such as W shaped patterns, then it would be worth investigating.

Comment: right. It is introduced in 12c only. but we have to use that in practice.

Answer (score -1):

Using `LAG` function you can compare values from different rows. I assume the resultset you showed is ordered by another column named `position`.

```
select value
from
    (select value, 
            lag(value,-1) over (order by position) prev, 
            lag(value,1) over (order by position) next
    from table)
where value > prev
and value > next
```

Comment: I am getting error [Error] Execution (20: 7): ORA-30484: missing window specification for this function

Comment: @Shravan Yadav: Edited, syntax should be correct now.

Comment: You can't have analytic functions in the WHERE clause.

Comment: yes it is not allowed. still getting error [Error] Execution (40: 7): ORA-30483: window  functions are not allowed here